# I want to take a number from the user and if he type a character or anything else i want him to enter the number again

Tags: c++

```
int x;

if(cin >> x)
    cout << "True" << endl;
else
{
    cin >> x;
}
```

It supposes to let me enter the number again but it's end the program without taking the number again

Comment: `cin>>x` won't return false if the input is not a number, you need to check the input yourself.

Comment: You need to use a loop.

Comment: Use goto statement: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_goto_statement.htm

Comment: @Vincent How will `goto` solve his issue?

Comment: @vincent it didn't work also

Comment: @DimChtz how can i check the input by myself ?

Comment: @Abdalrahmanshebani You can do `cin >> x; if ( !cin ) { /* input failed */ }` but it will accept anything that starts with a number.

Comment: @DimChtz I am assuming he wants to check if a number is entered, and if not, try it again. You can accomplish this using a goto statement when the number is not entered. (Off course after input validation)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to get the input as `string`, use `regex` to check if it's a number and if it is convert it to an `int`, otherwise ask for input again. Here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main() {

    std::regex rx(R"((?:^|\s)([+-]?[[:digit:]]+(?:\.[[:digit:]]+)?)(?=$|\s))");

    std::string line;
    int n;

    while ( std::getline(std::cin, line) ) {

        if ( std::regex_match(line, rx) ) {

            // Input is number
            n = std::stoi( line );
            std::cout << n << "\n";

            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```